# Flask session doesn't refresh

Tags: python, flask, google-oauth

I am creating a simple flask app for google oauth2. I am facing problems when for different user the session show that they are already registered. It is completely random. Sometime user go into the oauth flow, but most of the time it return the text I have set once I get the credentials which is 
`"Thank you for registering :)"`. Where am I making mistake?

```
import flask
import logging
from oauth2client import client
from manage_auth import store_user_info, get_user_info


app = flask.Flask(__name__)
SCOPES = [
    'email',
    'profile',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    # Add other requested scopes.
]

CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_secret_web.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'my_app_name'

@app.route('/')
def index():
  if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
    return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('oauth2callback'))
  credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials.from_json(flask.session['credentials'])
  if credentials.access_token_expired:
    return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('oauth2callback'))
  else:
      return "Thank you for registering :)"


@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
  flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
      CLIENT_SECRET,
      scope=' '.join(SCOPES),
      redirect_uri=flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)
     )

  if 'code' not in flask.request.args:
    auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    return flask.redirect(auth_uri)
  else:
    #get auth code
    auth_code = flask.request.args.get('code')

    #get credentials
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)
    flask.session['credentials'] = credentials.to_json()

    #get info and store credentials
    user_info = get_user_info(credentials)
    email_address = user_info.get('email')
    flask.session['user_id'] = email_address

    if credentials.refresh_token is not None:
        store_user_info(email_address, user_info, credentials)
    return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  import uuid
  app.secret_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
  app.debug = True
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8889)
```

Comment: Session.pop solved the problem.  But now the app hangs if I open three for client simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pop the session out each time you logout.Hoping this may be of any help!

Comment: Do you mean I should put flask.session.pop('credentials', None) before the thank you message ?

Comment: This solved the problem. But now I am facing another problem. The app hangs if I open three four client simultaneously

Comment: Yah i mean't to pop the session. Meanwhile what is the new error you facing. Can you give me more insights like stack trace or log file.